# importing a spreadsheet with cell-anchored images into an SQLite database

Tags: excel, pandas, sqlite, google-sheets, blob

In brief: how can I export a Google Sheets spreadsheet to an SQLite database without losing the cell-anchored images?

In long:
   Google Sheets, Excel, and SQLite all allow cell-anchored images.  Furthermore, Sheets supports exporting to Excel without loss of such images; and companion programs such as "DB Browser for SQLite",
   and LibreOffice also support cell-anchored images. However, I have not been able to export a Sheet (or an Excel spreadsheet)
   to SQLite, though I have tried all the obvious possibilities, and some less obvious ones as well.  In the latter
   category, two attempts are noteworthy:

a) The Python package openpyxl explicitly says
      "All other workbook / worksheet attributes are not copied - e.g. Images, Charts."

b) Python's `pandas` is more promising, because of the `dtype` parameter of `read_excel`.  Supposedly,
      specifying this as `object` should allow preservation of objects such as cell-anchored images.

Here then is one of my (failed) attempts to use pandas to achieve the desired result:

```
import sqlite3
import pandas as pd

filename="Test"
con=sqlite3.connect(filename+".db")

wb = pd.read_excel('Test.xlsx',sheet_name = None, header = None, dtype = object)

for sheet in wb:
    print(sheet)  # Sheet1
    # print( wb[sheet].columns )
    wb[sheet].to_sql(sheet, con, index=False)
con.commit()
con.close()
```

Any solution, whether Python-based or not, would be gladly accepted.

### Clarification

I'm aware of several techniques for extracting all the images into separate files but am looking for a fully automated technique (presumably some kind of script) for performing the conversion.  Whether or not such a technique extracts the images as an intermediate step is immaterial.

I've also tried adding `dtype` specifications in the call to `to_sql`, but to no avail.

### Addendum

@Stef's original program requires that the images to be copied are all in named columns, and that these names are either known or can be determined.  The first assumption is acceptable, and the second can be relaxed by simply writing:

```
dtype = object
```

in the call to `read_excel`.

Comment: have you seen this: https://www.penwatch.net/cms/images_from_excel/

Comment: @404pio - Yes, I’m familiar with the workarounds. Thanks

Comment: what is the error you get?

Comment: Who said anything about an “error”?

Comment: What I usually do is creating a Powershell script for handling the XL files ( either extracting macros or in this case images ) then you just call the powershell command in my Python script using subprocess.run ( .... )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no direct way, but you can use [`openpyxl`](https://pypi.org/project/openpyxl/) [version 2.5.5](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/changes.html#id79) or later to read images and manually put them into the dataframe.

In the following minimal example I use pandas `read_excel` to first get all the data, except the images. The crucial point is to import the image column as `object` type in order to be able to assign the images later. Otherwise this empty column will get all `NaN`s and a float data type.
Then we read the images from Excel using `openpyxl` and import them into the dataframe. The `ref` attribute of the image holds an `_io.BytesIO` stream. Its pointer points to the end (EOF) after loading the workbook, so we'll have to rewind it first (`img.ref.seek(0)`). (btw, there seems to be a bug in the `img.path` names in `openpyxl`: I get the same path `/xl/media/image1.png` for all three images whereas it is `image{1,2,3}.png` in the xlsx).
Anchor row/column values are zero based (`img.anchor.idx_base == 0`), so we have to account for the header row when computing the `iat` position in the dataframe (and possible index columns if any). Finally we export the dataframe to SQL using `to_sql`.

```
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl
import sqlite3

file_name = 'so58068593.xlsx'
sheet_name = 'Tabelle1'

# read data into dataframe
df = pd.read_excel(file_name, sheet_name=sheet_name, dtype=object)

# read images and add them to dataframe
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(file_name)
ws = wb[sheet_name]
for img in ws._images:
    img.ref.seek(0)
    df.iat[img.anchor.to.row-1, img.anchor.to.col] = img.ref.read()

# export to sqlite
with sqlite3.connect(file_name + ".db") as con:
    df.to_sql(sheet_name, con=con)
```

[Excel file](https://gofile.io/?c=Cywqr4) (images taken from [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_der_Nationalflaggen)):

[image]

SQLite database viewed in DB Browser for SQLite:

[image]

This is just a minimal example. If you don't know in advance where the images are in your `xlsx` file, you could first iterate over the `images` collection of the worksheet and check which columns/rows you need for the images in your dataframe, then append them to the dataframe (if not already there) and only then assign the images. Please note, however, that in `xlsx` you can have data in a cell and at the same time an image achored to this cell, which of course can't be mapped to a database table or pandas dataframe. The reason is that images are not the content of a cell but just anchored to this cell (you could even have several images anchored to the same cell).

Comment: Thank you!  Please see the Addendum regarding the small change that is sufficient to achieve an acceptable degree of automation.  If you wouldn't mind making that change, I'll gladly accept your answer. Also, I'd appreciate it if you could point me to relevant documentation for _images, which seems to be undocumented in the official openpyxl documentation. Thank you again!

Comment: Regarding the bug - I can confirm it's there. What would you suggest would be the best way to file a bug report?

Comment: I have the dtype in my call to read_excel for the 'Flag' column, if you put it generally, then it will apply to all columns - is this the intended behavior by you?

Comment: Yes, I don't want to lose any of the images.  Your point about potentially overwriting a value is important, but your program can evidently be modified e.g. to produce a warning if a value is overwritten.

Comment: Regarding the documentation: there seems to be no official documentation, I just deduced it from the source code and by trail and error. Regarding the bug - I didn't file a bug report as I don't use the image path propertie as load_workbook already loads the images (bug reports go here https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl/issues?status=new&status=open).

Comment: So it seems the really important "bug" is that ._images is undocumented... and yet the omission together with the underscore suggests that ._images is intentionally undocumented.  If that's the case, the "bug" would be that there is no documented way to obtain the images.  Does that seem correct to you?

Comment: Yes, at least I didn't find any other (documented) way.

Comment: See https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl/issues/1350/no-documented-way-to-do-what-_images-does

Comment: Instead of `seek(0)` and `read()`, you can simply use `getvalue()`.

Comment: Also, why do you use `anchor.to` rather than `anchor._from`? Or the barycenter of the two, taking offsets into account.

Comment: There is a nice write-up about `twoCellAnchor` here: http://polymathprogrammer.com/2009/11/30/how-to-insert-an-image-in-excel-open-xml/